# Get lat, long from QGIS polyline shapefile

Tags: qgis, line

I develop in C#. I want to develop a tool which needs to read the poly line coordinates. QGis is a very good tool that my users can use to generate a polyline .shp file. But how will I be able to access the coordinates(lat,long).

Comment: You will need a library that is able to read the shapefile format.  A minute or two with your favorite search engine ought to turn up some answers.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, because that other question is about Arc, and this appears more general. That said, the comment about showing some research is more than valid. If you need a start, some of the answers in that other question might be applicable (e.g. SharpMap or DotSpatial).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the OSGEO package in python to easily read shapefile geometry data, and it looks like GDAL and OGR has bindings for [C#](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) as well.

[Here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-geometry-from-each-feature-in-a-layer) are some of the code example I used when using the python library. I'm sure the C# bindings aren't far off.

Here's an example of how I used the package.

```
from osgeo import ogr

# We will read a shapefile in this example
shapefile_path = '/some/path/data/shapefiles/regions.shp'
sf = ogr.Open(shapefile_path)

# Grabs layer 'regions'
lyr = sf.GetLayer(os.path.split(os.path.splitext(shapefile_path)[0])[1])

# Grab our first feature of the shapefile
# This example assumes each feature is a polygon, but it shouldn't be much
#+ different for a polyline    
polygon = lyr.GetNextFeature()

# Iterate all features in the shapefile
while polygon is not None:
    # Iterate all rings in the polygon
    for ring in polygon:
        # Iterate all coordinate pairs the ring
        for point in ring.GetPoints():
            coord = list(point)

            # Do something with the coordinate (coord)

    # Move on to the next polygon
    polygon = lyr.GetNextFeature()
```